# How to read this array object getting from firebase realtime database in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

''
debug Print returning the follwing objects
**{-N5sd_T8qmxmGdd_9JcZ: {catName: French}, -N5sdTINTCXa3MvRQIOZ: {catName: English}, -N5sdYF96eRiTWJd-NrR: {catName: Tamil}**
How I can read this response from firebase and display in simple Text widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final userDb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users");
  userDb.get().then((value) {
  if (value.value != null) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> usersList = value.value;
    usersList.forEach((key, data) {
  //get key to update that document
     log(key.toString); 
 //get data to update the data in that key
    log(data.toString)


     }
   }
  });
```